# Material UI Responsive based Appbar covering over main contect? How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to write out a website with responsive-based app bar with a drawer tagged onto it. I am using this design found at https://medium.com/@tsubasakondo_36683/create-responsive-drawer-menu-with-react-material-ui-617a42764b69 and modifying it accordingly. But unfortunately, I am getting this issue, in which the drawer covers the portion of the content trying to be displayed. Please know that I have seen similar questions on this site, but I couldn't figure out how to solve them or the answers were kind of vague. Any help would be much appreciated, please let me know if I need to clarify anything further. All of this is using Material UI components.

[image]

Here is my code:

Material UI App-Bar

```js
//Used code: https://medium.com/@tsubasakondo_36683/create-responsive-drawer-menu-with-react-material-ui-617a42764b69

//Picture/Icon Imports
import home from "../Icons/home.png";
import about from "../Icons/about.png";
import contact from "../Icons/contact.png";
import resume from "../Icons/resume.png";
import minecraft from "../Icons/minecraft.png";
import github from "../Icons/github.png"

import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import Hidden from '@material-ui/core/Hidden';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
    },
    drawer: {
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            width: drawerWidth,
            flexShrink: 0,
        },
    },
    appBar: {
        zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            display: 'none',
        },
    },
    toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
    drawerPaper: {
        width: drawerWidth
    },
    content: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        padding: theme.spacing(0),
    },
    closeMenuButton: {
        marginRight: 'auto',
        marginLeft: 0,
    },
}));
function NavBar() {
    const DifferentPages = [
        {Text: "Home", location: "/", Image: home},
        {Text: "About", location: "/about", Image: about},
        {Text: "Contact", location: "/contact", Image: contact},
        {Text: "Resume", location: "/resume", Image: resume},
        {Text: "Minecraft", location: "/minecraft", Image: minecraft},
    ]

    const classes = useStyles();
    const theme = useTheme();
    const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);
    function handleDrawerToggle() {
        setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen)
    }
    const drawer = (
        <div>
            <List>
                {DifferentPages.map((Text) => (
                    <ListItem button component={Link} to={Text.location}>
                        <img src={Text.Image} width={"25"} height={"25"}/>
                        <ListItemText primary={Text.Text} />
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
                <ListItem button href={"example.com"}>
                    <img src={github} width={"25"} height={"25"}/>
                    <ListItemText>
                        Github
                    </ListItemText>
                </ListItem>
            </List>
        </div>
    );
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton
                        color="inherit"
                        aria-label="Open drawer"
                        edge="start"
                        onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
                        className={classes.menuButton}
                    >
                        <MenuIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
                        Responsive drawer
                    </Typography>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>

            <nav className={classes.drawer}>
                <Hidden smUp implementation="css">
                    <Drawer
                        variant="temporary"
                        anchor={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'right' : 'left'}
                        open={mobileOpen}
                        onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
                        classes={{
                            paper: classes.drawerPaper,
                        }}
                        ModalProps={{
                            keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
                        }}
                    >
                        <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerToggle} className={classes.closeMenuButton}>
                            <CloseIcon/>
                        </IconButton>
                        {drawer}
                    </Drawer>
                </Hidden>
                <Hidden xsDown implementation="css">
                    <Drawer
                        className={classes.drawer}
                        variant="permanent"
                        classes={{
                            paper: classes.drawerPaper,
                        }}
                    >
                        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
                        {drawer}
                    </Drawer>
                </Hidden>
            </nav>
            <div className={classes.content}>
                <div className={classes.toolbar} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
NavBar.propTypes = {
    container: PropTypes.object,
};
export default NavBar;
```

App.js: NOTE** in App.js, I can add style={{paddingleft:240}} to the div before routes and it kind of remedy this issue, however, once the screen is small enough (i.e.like mobile) view and the drawer is hidden, 240px padding is still there.
(edited down for simplicity - content still the same)

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { HashRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

//Page Routes
import NavigationAppBar from "./Navigation-Bar/NavigationAppBar";
import Home from './Page-Information/main';

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <NavigationAppBar/>
            <div>
                <Routes>
                    <Route exact path='/' exact element={<Home />} />
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js: (edited down for simplicity - content still the same)

```js
import React from 'react';

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Example</h3>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: please check the Persistent drawer example.  https://mui.com/components/drawers/#persistent-drawer `drawerwidth` should be in `App.js` from there you can pass it to your `NavigationAppBar`. then dynamic margin should be set in `div' tag where you have added your routes. `Home.js` or other files have nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: I do apologize and thank you for your help. I did take a look a persistent drawer example code (https://codesandbox.io/s/j6ltj?file=/demo.js) and I am having a little difficulty transcribing to the reccomendations you have given to me. Since the demo given is really just doing all of the work into a single js file, I don't have enough knowledge to completely understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forked the default persistent demo updated it into separate files.

[image: Edit elastic-elion-oslzb]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this and your example helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can add breakpoint for smaller device to remove margin or padding as appropriate.

```
const Main = styled("main", { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open" })(
  ({ theme, open }) => ({
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    }),
    marginLeft: `-${drawerWidth}px`,
    ...(open && {
      transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
      }),
      marginLeft: 0
    }),
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      //add CSS here.
    }

  })
);
```